# is timezoneinfo.converttime works with some devices only at xamarin froms?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin forms in my android app I'm getting the datetime that I converted to
Egypt time but some devices read it nulls or countries I don't know the reason really but some others read it?
and that is my code

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
var test = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(date, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Africa/Cairo"));
```

Comment: Try debugging the content of TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones() in the problematic devices

Comment: @Martheen it works fine with android 10 android 9 , so you mean I install all supported devices and test them all?

Comment: Just write a simple app that list the content of TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones(), install it on the problematic  devices, and see if they actually contain "Africa/Cairo". I suspect either Xamarin, Mono or the vendor ROM modification misspelled the ID

Comment: @Martheen but how can I know the problematic devices ? all I  could do and I did right now I installed simulator at VS 2019 from android 5 to android 10 all works fine !!

Comment: I said in the problematic devices. You said you're getting some devices read it null, so either manually contact the owner of those devices to install your app, or push an update that will do it automatically and send the result to you through either crash report or user facing dialog

Comment: @Martheen I made update to read the device model and that is one of them (Xiaomi Redmi Note 8T) how track the issue? sorry and thanks for help

Comment: Collect the list of timezone id from the problematic device. Alternatively, you can list it first, then use the item that contain the word Cairo or Egypt.

Comment: Aha i will try to do it thanks bro

Answer (score 1):

It might help you

```
 DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;

 TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Africa/Cairo Standard Time");
 TimeSpan utcOffset = timeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffset(now);
 DateTime cairoTime = new DateTime(now.Ticks + utcOffset.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Local);
```

Comment: I wll test it and see thank you dude.  I guess all redmi note devices has the same issue

Comment: You should get a  redmi note device and debug on that device to see what problem it is.